# Unable to clear text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitextfield

I am adding text field to a table view cell, i am able to edit the text field, but i am not able to access the default clear button. I checked the frames , They are

```
Cell Frame : {{0, 70.790001}, {703, 40}}, 
textFieldFrame : {{171, 0}, {505, 39}}
```

If i decrease the width of text field i am able to access the clear button, by doing so, the design will be disturbed.

i also checked if any view is overlapping text field, but i am sure that text field is the top most subview of cell.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution, Actually the issue was the textfield, which was exceeding the superview bounds, Changing the frame of text field within the bounds of view fixed the problem.

**Conclusion**:

Make sure that the `textfield` is within the bounds of its `superview`

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath set text must be empty.

```
yourTextfield.text = @"";
```